# error: cannot resolve overloaded function based on conversion to type ‘int’

Tags: c++

I wrote the following code :

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int lengthOfLastWord(string A) {
    int m= A.size();
    int i=0;
    while(i<m)
    {
        if(A[i]==' ')
        {
            int count=0;
            i++;
            while(A[i]!=' ')
            {
                count++;
                i++;
            }
        }
        else
        i++;
    }
    return count;
}
int main()
{
    string A;
    getline(cin,A);
    cout<<lengthOfLastWord(A);
}
```

But it is showing the following error

```
error: cannot resolve overloaded function ‘count’ based on conversion to type ‘int’
```

I am unable to understand why is it showing this error and what should I do to fix it.
Please help me.
Thankyou

Comment: You're missing the concept of variable scope. Your `count` variable is decalred inside the if statement in your function. It is unavailable outside that if statement. In particular it's not avilable at the end of the function where you do `return count;`. If you want `count` to be available there, then move the decalreation of `count` to the top of your function. Plus don't do `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` or `using namespace std;` which just obscure the error message. On a bad day, those two statements will cause a bug in an otherwise working program. Don't use them.

Comment: This function can be written much more simply. Read about [`std::basic_string::find_last_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_of).

Answer (score 9):

Inside the `if` scope, your `count` variable is colliding with (technically "shadowing") [`std::count`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count).  However, your local `count` does not exist in the scope of your `return` statement, so the compiler is trying to use the only `count` that it knows about at that point, which is `std::count`.

This is a great example of why `using namespace std` and `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` are both bad ideas.  If proper includes and namespaces were used, this code would have given you a much clearer compile error:

```
error: 'count' was not declared in this scope
```

Answer (score 4):

The most direct reason is because your `count` variable is defined in the `if` scope, and not available in the scope of `return` statement.

However, the error you are seeing is confusing, since you have `using namespace std` in your code, and it makes completely unrelated (for your purposes) function `std::count` visible everywhere in your program, including your `return` statement. From the compiler perspective, you are trying to return a pointer to `std::count`, but since this function is overloaded template, compiler doesn't know which one you are trying to return - thus the phrasing of the errror.

If you remove the `using namespace std` from your code, which you should have never had in the first place, your code will still fail to compile, but error message would be way more easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to rename your count variable to something else like `total`.

The compiler is considering `std::count` function instead of the count variable which is `int`.

Comment: `std::count` is all that's available at the site of the error.